# Facebook sdk generating keyhash

Tags: android

I am using this code to get my development key hash

```
public class Myap extends Application {
    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();

    }
    public void printHashkey()
    {
        // Add code to print out the key hash
        try {
            PackageInfo info = getPackageManager().getPackageInfo(
                    "com.vitmail.android",
                    PackageManager.GET_SIGNATURES);
            for (Signature signature : info.signatures) {
                MessageDigest md = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA");
                md.update(signature.toByteArray());
                Log.d("KeyHash:", Base64.encodeToString(md.digest(), Base64.DEFAULT));
            }
        } catch (PackageManager.NameNotFoundException e) {

        } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {

        }
    }
}
```

But it is generating the same error everytime

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.vitmail.android/com.vitmail.android.navbar_fragments.NavigationActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.content.Context android.content.Context.getApplicationContext()' on a null object reference
```

Please tell me where is the mistake?

Comment: you have to search `What is java.lang.NullPointerException` on stackoverflow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try to my code.............

```
  public void getFbKeyHash(String packageName) {

        try {
            PackageInfo info = getPackageManager().getPackageInfo(
                    packageName,
                    PackageManager.GET_SIGNATURES);
            for (Signature signature : info.signatures) {
                MessageDigest md = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA");
                md.update(signature.toByteArray());
                Log.d("YourKeyHash :", Base64.encodeToString(md.digest(), Base64.DEFAULT));
                System.out.println("YourKeyHash: " + Base64.encodeToString(md.digest(), Base64.DEFAULT));
            }
        } catch (PackageManager.NameNotFoundException e) {

        } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {

        }

    }
```

call them OnCreate() method ..............

```
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);
        context = this;
        getFbKeyHash( "com.vitmail.android");


   }
```